# Django Logout Button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views, django-login

This may seem like a silly question but I can't find anything to help.
How would you create a logout button on every view like the one available in the admin page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use templates inheritance:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance
or include tag:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include

Example with template inheritance:
We have a base template for all pages on our application:

## base.html

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <a href="/logout">logout</a>  # or use the "url" tag: {% url logout_named_view %}

    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

## other_pages.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content">....</div>
    ....
    ....
{% endblock %}
```

Now, we have a logout link on all pages inherited from the base.html

Example with include tag:

## user_panel.html

```
<div class="user_panel">
    <a href="/logout">logout</a>
</div>
```

## other_pages

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    {% include "user_panel.html" %}
    ...
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

I recommend for a solution to your problem using template inheritance

Answer (score 1):

**I wanted to extend the approved reply with my solution. What i did is:**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout
```

> If you want a method that checks if the user is already logged in you can create a function:

```
def UserLoggedIn(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated == True:
    username = request.user.username
else:
    username = None
return username
```

*`this checks if the user is already logged in and returns its username`*

> then create a request function that checks if the username is not `None` (or just ommit the if statement)

```
def logout_view(request):
    username = UserLoggedIn(request)
    if username != None:
        logout(request)
        return redirect(your_home_view_here)
```

> lastly just import your view into `urls.py` and create a path in urlpatterns

```
path('logout/', logout_view, name='logout')
```